# Cannot upload Archive to iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I have added Health Kit in latest build of my app and trying to upload it to store. I have added relevant privacy descriptions to the info.plist file but it still returns me an error. [image]

Here is my info.plist and localizations:
I am wondering what might cause this weird error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you might want to add a better description than "Used to access your HealthKit data.", try something more descriptive like "Uses HealthKit data to do x, y, and z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to write these lines in info plist

```
NSCalendarUsageDescription

Privacy - Camera Usage Description

Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
```

Then you have to do this

```
Please follow these steps : 

1) Launch Application Loader.
2) In the top menu bar, click Application Loader > Preferences.
3) Choose Advanced.
4) Under Transfer Protocol, deselect Aspera.
5) Close the Preferences window and proceed with the delivery.
```

Comment: Also removing derived data helped.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rename `infoPlist.strings` to `InfoPlist.strings` (notice the
   capital I)
2. Insert the key of the string into the actual value in your usage description key in `Info.plist`, like this:

[image]

(Step 2 does matter, I submitted an app to the App Store without these inserted and although my app showed the descriptions properly in runtime Apple's process to check apps when they're uploaded did not like it)

I'd recommend cleaning out your build folder, deleting the app from your phone and then reinstalling with these changes just to make sure everything starts off clean and you can diagnose any issues from there.